# How to resolve Axios Error whlle using Google-Auth using firebase?

Tags: next.js, axios, firebase-authentication, chat, internal-server-error

```
import { CHECK_USER_ROUTE } from "@/utils/ApiRoutes";
import { firebaseAuth } from "@/utils/FirebaseConfig";
import axios from "axios";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";
import {FcGoogle} from "react-icons/fc";

function login() {
const router = useRouter()
const handleLogin = async () => {
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const {user:{displayName:name,email,photoUrl:profileImage},} = await      signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth,provider);
try {
if(email) {
const {data} = await axios.post(CHECK_USER_ROUTE,{email});
console.log({data});
if(!data.status){
router.push("/onboarding");
}
}
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}
};
return( <div className="flex justify-center items-center bg-panel-header-background h-screen w-   screen flex-col gap-6">
<div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 text-white">
<Image src="/whatsapp.gif" alt="Whatsapp" height={300} width={300}/>
<span className="text-7xl">Whatsapp</span>
</div>
<button className="flex items-center justify-center gap-7 bg-search-input-container-background p-5 rounded-lg"onClick={handleLogin}>
<FcGoogle className="text-4xl"/>
<span className="text-white text-2xl">Login with Google</span>
</button>
</div>
)
}

export default login;
```

This is my code. I am working on a chat application.When i console.log the data I dont get the actual data instead I get error as AxiosError as well as an Internal Server Error.

**The AxiosError :**
AxiosError
code
:
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 500"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
:
{data: '\n\n\n<meta char…lib\router\index.js:47:12)\n\n\n', status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:125:66)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error
**Internal Server Error :**
POST http://localhost:3005/api/auth/check-user 500 (Internal Server Error)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftZtU.png)

I don't know how to solve it. This is how I expect to get the result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlOgM.png)